# undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null

I'm adding comments to my `Questions` model, and I've run into an error.

When viewing the page, I get this error:

```
undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass
```

The error is resulting from line 30:

```
30: <% @question.comments.each do |comment| %>
```

I can't figure out what's happening, though.

My controllers, models, and view is in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/snapapps/a4c77e43cf9f1cab9d0a)

Could you help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have @question variable. Sth like this:

```
@question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
```

In the proper method of your view - You didn't write is it a show, or maybe index.

Comment: Index, sorry. I think I titled it that in the Gist

Comment: So add this line to your index method in CommentsController.
Moreover, as a general rule, if you don't know where the bug is, and you are giving a link to gist with many files, it's always good to include config/routes.rb file.

Comment: you are loading all the comments in the index action. Then why are you calling @question.comments? Why can't you directly use @comments? If you want to only show the comments for a particular question, you will have to pass the question_id to your index action. You can scope your comments with question. Route will look something like /questions/:question_id/comments.

Comment: A guide to nested resource: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources